# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Html entities in model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, customization

I have redefined names of ActiveRecord model by this way

```
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "<b>Custom email</b>"
        password: "<b>Custom password</b>"
```

I would like to get such output in my browser:

***"Custom email** must be not empty*

but a get

```
<b>Custom email</b> must be not empty
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally with translations you can suffix the key name with "_html" in order to say that its output should not be escaped:

```
user:
  email_html: "<b>Custom email</b>"
```

You should try that first but I don't think ActiveRecord will automatically look up that key.

Instead, where you output the form labels you may need to supply the translation key yourself:

```
<%= f.label :email, t("activerecord.attributes.user.email_html") %>
```

Or:

```
<%= f.label :email, t("activerecord.attributes.user.email").html_safe %>
```

I think `html_safe` is still valid.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for response. But I don't use names of attrs in a way *<%= f.label :email, t("activerecord.attributes.user.email_html") %>*. Names of attrs are used by ActiveRecord automatically. When I try to suffix the key attr, ActiveRecord don't see this key (

Comment: There would be other ways involving various hacks. Although if you are doing no more than your example indicates (surrounding the label text in `<b>`) then you should just style it via CSS.